# Flask-Login: How to set "blueprint_login_views" to have blueprint specific login_view

Tags: python, flask-login

Any help on how to use login_view for each blueprint? I did a search on Google, your blogs, and every possible sources but didn't find any working examples.

I have 4 blueprints as below:

```
admin(__init__, route.py)
customer(__init__, route.py)
partners(__init__, route.py)
auth(__init__, route.py)
```

`auth` is going to handle as a central point for different type(social+regular) of authentication.

And I am using `@login_required` for all the possible routes under different profiles.
But the problem is; `login_manager.login_view` only allows me to setup only one login view. I want to have separate login_views so that my respective authorization can be redirected to respective blueprints and so on and I can have a clear control on who(role) is logging in and it's respective route.

I only found something

```
@<a href="http://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.LoginManager.login_view">LoginManager.login_view blueprint_login_views</a>
```

that when `unauthorized()` is called it can first check `blueprint_login_views` and if not set then `login_views` is checked and then `"HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) error"` is raised if nothing is set. But there is no working example how to set `blueprint_login_views` through `login_manager`. Please help.

Comment: I myself could solve this now. I removed "login_manager.login_view" and
added the below block in app/__init__.py after the blueprints are loaded.
[code]
login_manager.blueprint_login_views = {
        'partners'  : '/partner/login',
        'customers' : '/customer/login',
        'admin' : '/admin/login',
    }
[code]

Comment: If you solved it, you can always answer (and accept) your own question so that other users who stumble upon this page might have an easier time finding the solution. This would also yield proper formatting which is more readable then a simple comment.

Answer (score 6):

OP's original answer properly formatted:

> I myself could solve this now. I removed "login_manager.login_view"
>   and added the below block in app/**init**.py after the blueprints are
>   loaded.
>
> ```
> login_manager.blueprint_login_views = {
>     'partners': '/partner/login',
>     'customers': '/customer/login',
>     'admin' : '/admin/login',
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works great. If you have two tables that you need to query from for each blueprint authentication, you can do:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    x = Users.query.get(str(user_id))
    if x == None:
        x = Admins.query.get(str(user_id))
    return x
```

This resides where you declare the flask app instance typically **init**.py file(not empty)